# Pandas column dType of array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data I am having trouble modeling in my data frame, such that it's easy to work with and saves on memory. The data is read from a CSV file with 4 columns ID, Date, LID and Data and 600k rows. The ID, Date, and LID are a multi-hierarchical index and the Data is a time-series of 600 points.

My current setup of the dataframe looks like this:

```
  ID       Date      LID       Data
00112   11-02-2014    I    [ 0, 1, ... ]
00112   11-02-2014    II   [ 1, 2, ... ]
00112   30-07-2015    I    [ 5, 7, ... ]
00112   30-07-2015    II   [ 3, 2, ... ]
```

My problem is that with this structure I have not been able to restrict the array type in the Data column, I know this is possible easily when the type of data is not an array but say for example an integer.

So my question is, is this a sensible data frame structure and if so how can I restrict the array elements of the Data column to say int16 when reading the CSV file.

Below is the structure I could define where the Data column is split into 600 columns one for each data points, such that I can easily define the dType for each column. Maybe this is a better structure?

```
  ID       Date      LID   0  1  2  3  4
00112   11-02-2014    I    0  1  5  6  7
00112   11-02-2014    II   2  4  5  3  4
00112   30-07-2015    I    5  7  1  1  2
00112   30-07-2015    II   3  2  8  7  1
```

The structure of the file is like so: [Data](https://pastebin.com/zS42GpKF)

The resulting code that reads the CSV file and first parses the 600 point data columns as an array and then concatenates the 600 column dataframe to the original dataframe.

```
import ast
df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=names, dtype=dTypes)
df.Data = df.Data.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Data', axis=1),pd.DataFrame(df.Data.tolist(),
                    dtype=np.int16)], axis=1)

df = df.set_index(['PatientID', 'Date', 'LeadID'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second startegy is better, as you can easily change the datatypes. For instance, for a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]: 
    ID        Date LID      Data
0  112  11-02-2014   I  [ 0, 1 ]
1  112  11-02-2014  II  [ 1, 2 ]
2  112  30-07-2015   I  [ 5, 7 ]
3  112  30-07-2015  II  [ 3, 2 ]
```

You can construct a new dataframe where the data in `Data` are of type int16 as follows:

```
In [94]: pd.concat([df.drop('Data', axis=1),pd.DataFrame(df.Data.tolist(),
                    dtype=np.int16)], axis=1)
Out[94]: 
    ID        Date LID  0  1
0  112  11-02-2014   I  0  1
1  112  11-02-2014  II  1  2
2  112  30-07-2015   I  5  7
3  112  30-07-2015  II  3  2

In [96]: df.dtypes
Out[96]: 
ID       int64
Date    object
LID     object
0        int16
1        int16
dtype: object
```

**EDIT**: if the column Data contain strings like `"[1, 2, ...]"` and not lists you need to convert the strings back to lists as follows:

```
import ast
df.Data = df.Data.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Data', axis=1),pd.DataFrame(df.Data.tolist(),
                        dtype=np.int16)], axis=1)
```

Comment: That's super. Quick question do you know if I can construct the dataframe directly without concatenation? As is I create the dataframe by specifying the names and instantiating the dataframe from a 600k length list where each element is a tuple ('IDval', 'Dateval', 'LIDval', list('Datavals'))

Comment: @guano could you please share the structure of the csv ?

Comment: When performing the concatenation I get the error. Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

Comment: The error happens when the there are no columns besides the index. To resolve this I just wait with setting the index until after concatenating. See my edit for a code that includes your solution for my use case.

Comment: Is there a good way if the size of Data is unknown?